# Page overflowing with gird repeat auto-fit

Tags: html, css

I have a grid with an auto-fit. It's working fine, but on smaller (< 350) screens, it's overflowing. How can fixe this? Basically have 350 as long as it's possible and shrink otherwise.

```
 .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr));
        gap: 1rem;
      }
      .item {
        background-color: crimson;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 2rem;
      }
```

```
<div class="grid">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest another property inside `minmax()`, e.g. `min()`:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(100%, 350px), 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
}

.item {
  background-color: crimson;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just realised that you answered first, so accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should achieve what you're looking for:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min(350px, 100%), 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

Your minimum width was not responsive, so I've fixed that by adding a value of `100%` inside the `minmax` using `min()`.